# Function not call when button click

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have create a UIBUtton

```
editButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, -4, 30, 30)];
        [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteButton.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        editButton.hidden = YES;
        [editButton setTag:tag];
        [backView addSubview:editButton];
```

But control not jump to its definition where i check if button give its tag value on click or not.

-

```
(void)deleteObjectViewImage
{

    NSInteger index = editButton.tag;
    editButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it not work please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line instead of line in your code (colon removed after function name),

```
 [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: thanks. it works. But i still not get the tag value of clicked button.Instead of it it provide last button tag value.

Comment: make sure you are assigning different tags to both buttons.

Comment: i am just creating editbutton  and assigning tag (as you can see in first function)."[editButton setTag:tag];"where tag value is increment one by one. and in another function(delete.....) i want to store tag value in index. but it not return click button tag value.

Comment: if you are incrementing tag variable properly i don't understand why it is happening, also make sure you do not have any other button with same name.

Comment: i have done it. now it working. i want the tag property of Button beacause i have to delete image stored in plist according to tag value . i have also got sucess in delete the image but it don't how to reload plist.

Answer (score 1):

```
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

expects the function deleteObjectViewImage: to have one argument. But the function definition doesnt has any.

UPDATE:

```
-(void)deleteObjectViewImage: (id) sender
    {
    UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton *) sender;
        NSInteger index = clickedButton.tag;
        editButton.hidden = YES;
    }
```

and use

```
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: but i also don't want to send any value at calling time.And i have used the same synatx for other Uibutton and it work proprerly.

Comment: Then dont use ":". Just use [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; as said by iPhonePlayer

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the tag value of clicked button instead of last creaed button.

Comment: i have tried this. but it genrate error "sender was not declared in that scope."

Answer (score 0):

For getting Tag Value you have to write this code in Button Click event...

```
 -(IBAction)deleteObjectViewImage:(id)sender
 {
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
      NSLog(@"%d",btn.tag);
 }
```

Don't remove colon from

```
 [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hi marvin, may be i dont know this, but can we have return value as IBAction when we specify button targets progamatically?

Comment: It is `#define IBAction void`. Preprocessor changes it to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, -4, 30, 30)];
[editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteButton.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
editButton.hidden = YES;
[editButton setTag:tag];
[backView addSubview:editButton];


- (void)deleteObjectViewImage:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Button tag is %d",button.tag);
    button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
at this line erroe genrate"sender is not declared in that scope".

Comment: sender not declared? Are you sure the "sender" in the function parameter and when used for casting into button are spelled same?

Comment: Yes first check if they are spelled same.